# Connections strings used for different versions of Excel in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, connection-string

I have created a system in ASP.Net to merge multiple excel files into one. The different connection strings that I used for this are as follows

```
switch (Extension)
    {
        case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
            conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1};IMEX=1;'";
            break;
        case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
            conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR={1};IMEX=1;'";
            break;
    }
```

Earlier the system was working fine but from today it started giving me error as

**The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine**

Do I have to include any specific (new) dll with my application or do I need to change anything my application?

The type of files which I am trying to merge is

**Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet (.xls)**

Answer (score 0):

well you have to install the driver for excel you can find it over here [office driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734)

if you get the same error on IIS then you have to do some configuration which is mentioned in this [Link](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/280/solved-the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)

Comment: I did but it is still showing me the same error, also the system is working fine when I am running it through Visual Studio, the error is coming on server (remote).

Comment: I have uploaded this on a web server

Comment: I am using GoDaddy hosting for this but couldn't find these IIS settings there

Answer (score 0):

I also gone through the same problem. The possible cause is, there is different IIS settings on remote server, IIS settings are different. By default, IIS on 64-bit OS runs applications in 64-bit worker process and 64-bit processes cannot load 32-bit DLL.

Check out following link and make changes in remote servers IIS. (this solved my problem some time back)

[Solved - The Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered on the local machine](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/280/solved-the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)

Comment: I am using GoDaddy hosting for this but couldn't find these IIS settings there